# Can we store audit data on clients machine instead of a table from clients database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using triggers to audit data of a table from client's database. The trigger stores all the updates done by DML statements inside TransDetailAudit table.

Is there a way to store audit data on clients machine directly instead of TransDetailAudit table?

If yes then please guide!!!

Client dont want there audit data to be stored in a table.

Comment: That is a curious requirement. What happens if the user deletes the audit trail off their computer? How do you collect the audit trail afterwards? To store an audit trail locally, you need to get your application to write it. However this won't stop someone logging directly into the database and making a change. Only a table trigger  will capture that.

Comment: You got it right!!! It is a curious requirement :) :D Thanks for explaining cons of storing data on the machine. Haven't thought about audit trails as I am not sure about feasibility of the requirement.

Comment: To put it another way an audit trail on a client machine is unreliable, and an audit trial in a database is reliable and centralised.